# I made a half transparence in my 3d model, but i have shadows between models

Tags: mesh, transparency, shadows

[image][image]

I have shadows between the model, how can I delete?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Luis, and welcome. Please specify more closely what you mean by  'shadows between the model'. Perhaps point at the part you don't like. Is it the black sections? You can share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: i shared the files my friend, I have errors in the transparency of the model, I get those black shadows

Comment: It could be a number of things... it would be easier to see if you could share your file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=D1zOe8dy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/D1zOe8dy/)

Comment: i already shared the files

Answer (score 0):

I think at least part of your problem may be that your 'Transparent' light-paths are running out of bounce, and returning black before penetrating near-coincident surfaces.

Try this (or a bigger number) in your Render tab, and see whether it fixes your problem.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much my friend, it work, thanks, it was that

Comment: @LuisMiguelColmenaresMoreno   If you click the tick next to the answer, it's effectively marked as cleared up.